# Cron job on Mac OSX with axAMP

Tags: macos

I tried to running the pho script file under XAMPP on Mac OSX, but not working at all.

What I did is run it using this command:

```
 * * * * php -q /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mailing/apps/console/console.php send-campaigns >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Appreciate for helps :(

Comment: You do realize that this will start this script every minute, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I want running it every minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a `cronjob` there are 2 main parts you need to take notice of: **when** and **what**.

**When**

You can specify the minute (0-59), hour (0-23), day of month (1-31), month (1-12, Jan-Dec), day of week (0-6, Sun-Sat), in that order. The asterisk is a wildcard and will match anything.

```
Minute  Hour  Day of Month  Month  Day of Week
0       *     *             *      *             // Once at the start of every hour
*       *     *             *      *             // Once at the start of every minute
0       *     1             *      *             // Once at the start of every hour, on the 1st of every month
```

**When**

We have chosen WHEN we want something to happen, now we need to decide WHAT we want to happen. In your example you are executing a `PHP` script.

A very simple version of this would be as follows.

```
php /path/to/my/script.php someArgument
```

**Creating the cronjob**

Now we know **when** and **what**, we can piece it together.

Assuming we want to run a `PHP` script every minute:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/my/script.php someArgument
```

**So what went wrong?**

Your problem is that you only defined **four** time options, rather than **five**.

Try this:

```
* * * * * php -q /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mailing/apps/console/console.php send-campaigns >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Setting up a cronjob**

By default you should be able to SSH into your server and then do the following..

```
crontab -e // This opens the crontab for editing.

i // This will enable "insert" mode.

// Add your crontab line...
* * * * * php -q /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mailing/apps/console/console.php send-campaigns >/dev/null 2>&1

Press escape
Enter :w
Press enter
Enter :q
Press enter
```

Now to check that the crontab was successfully edited...

```
crontab -l
```

You should see the new crontab in there.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for reply, can you please give an example what exact command? I am really stuck on this

Comment: @user3573124 Tom gave you the line to put in your crontab. You edit the crontab with `crontab -e`

Comment: Oops sorry, my connection not loaded all content of the reply. Thanks, let me try it

Comment: I just added a lot more detail. Have a read and hopefully it will give you a better understanding of what you're doing :)

Comment: Already tried it, but said pattern not found for Applications. How to write a right path for this, tried use cd ~/ and ~/ but still no luck

Comment: Are you meaning to run this from a cronjob? Or do you just want to run a PHP script?

Comment: Yes I want to run this php script using cron job. The php script it self will check any of campaign on que on my application. The result I want from this is, when a user create a campaign and want to send it on specific time they set on the backend of the app.

Comment: I have just added even more information, explaining how to properly set up a cron. Please double check you've got it set up correctly

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the details explained for the steps. Is works now, big thanks for this.